# Wordpress delete_attachment hook doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, attachment

I'm developing a plugin that uses an XML file to store some attachments picked up from the media gallery.
I need to synch the media gallery and the XML file when an attachment is deleted from the Media Library, so the "delete_attachment" hook fits good for me.

BUT...it doesn't fire.
I tried the simpliest function but it doesn't work:

```
function onWpDelete( $targetID ){
    wp_die('Deleted attachment ' . $targetID);
}//onWpDelete
add_action('delete_attachment', 'onWpDelete');
```

It's stored in a functions.php file on the plugin directory that works for sure because there are other functions in there.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure add_action is called properly? Try adding another wp_die just before or after it.

Comment: Yeah. I tried before the function, just before the add_action and just after add_action and the wp_die is fired

Comment: I tried to delete an image from the Media Library:
Media Library -> selecting the image -> clicking on "delete permanentely" but the hook weren't fired.
Then I tried Media Library -> selectin the image -> Edit -> Delete permanentely and the hook were fired correctly.